# Library for solving a linear selection problem in a distributed memory machine

Tags: algorithms, c++, mpi, libraries

I need to solve a *very large* `O(10^10)` linear selection problem in a distributed memory machine, is there any library that will solve it for me?

In shared memory machines, e.g. `std::nth_element` does it in average `O(n)` but deterministic `O(n)` algorithms also exist. I could live with something worse as long as it's easy to implement. I would also prefer for it to work on input iterator/input ranges than to have linear complexity in order to save memory. I have a dataset that I want to postprocess and then use as input to the linear selection algorithm, it would be better if I could do it "on the fly". I also only want to solve the linear selection problem for certain values, and wouldn't care to solve it multiple times, once for each value.

Comment: Can you give us an order of magnitude for $n$?

Comment: The baseline algorithm to beat would be a short-circuited distributed-memory sort. You would be paying at extra $\log n$ factor though.

Comment: @BillBarth the order is `O(10^10)`.

Comment: @JackPoulson for the sort do I need to have all my values in memory? The point is that input iterators/ranges are one-way passes (you can't go back). However if I need to have everything in memory I can construct a random-access range from the input range.

Comment: Do you mean that each process would have a one-way iterator which allows for traversal over a subset of the list?

Comment: @JackPoulson Yes.

Comment: By any chance are you typically looking for entries close to one end of the list? For instance, finding the maximum or minimum entry can be done with a single pass on each process followed by a binary-tree reduction on a single entry. This algorithm obviously generalizes to finding the top/bottom $k$ entries (and therefore the $k$'th largest/smallest entry), though the communication cost is $O(k \log p)$ with $p$ processes.

Comment: @JackPoulson im intetersted at a pair of quantile values, e.g. (25%,75%) or (40%<60%).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to take a look at section 5.1 of this one of my papers:
  http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bangerth/publications/2010-distributed.pdf

The algorithm described there has complexity $O\left(\frac NP \log_2 P\right)$. The code has only some 20 lines.